# Vlookup column a and find highest version number in column b

Tags: vlookup

I have a list of part numbers in column A: in column B is a version number of the part number. The part number can be repeated and the version number is unique.  I want to lookup the part number in column a and find the highest version in column b.

```
 **Part #**       **Version**
1801234.         O
1801234.         2
1801234.         5  (i want to count only this one in version 5)
1812346.         1
1812346.         2
1812346.         3  (i want to Count only this one in version 3)
1908765.         0. (I want to count this one in version 0
1914515.         2
1914515.         3
```

End goal:  i have 27,000 unique part numbers in column a with associated versions in columb b. I want to know how many part numbers are in each version without duplicating the part numbers in the other version counts.  Example: 15 part numbers are at version 3 ( its assumed the progressed through ghe other versions.)

Comment: I have formatted your question for you, but you need to show the query you've tried so far so can help. Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/917209/edit) your question and show your query

Comment: Is this in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is Excel you can try the following recipe:

1. Sort both columns together, the first with part numbers (Col A) in **ascending** order and the second with version (Col B) in **descending** order: [Microsoft Office Excel Sorting Help](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654).  This isn't the same as sorting each column individually.
2. Using the filter command, determine unique part numbers and select the copy to cell range feature and copy them to say Column D: 
   [Microsoft Office Help Filtering Unique Values](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2)
3. Use EXCEL `VLOOKUP` formula in say Column E:  [Microsoft Office Help VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2)

   ```
   =VLOOKUP(Part # Col D,  Table Cols A&B, 2, FALSE)
   ```

What this formula does it take the part number from the unique list (Col D), looks through the part number from the first column of the table (Col A). The last parameter is `FALSE` which means find the **exact** part number.   Now when there is more than one valid answer it takes the **first**.

The second parameter is the table and the third parameter says which column from the table to return. We've selected 2 which is Col B, the version. Given that column B is in **descending** order it means when the first result from Col A is matched it matches the higher version from Col B.

The final step is using `COUNTIF` to count the number of parts at given version number. Apply it to column E